# Download parent pom from remote repository

Tags: maven-3

Is it possible (and how) to download the parent pom from a remote repository?

Why?
I have a project setup with many modules. The parent pom specifies dependencies to third-party jars. If one of the modules needs a new feature in a later version of one of the jars, I'd like to:

- update the parent pom with reference to the new jar
- update the single module pom referring to the new parent pom.

However, this breaks the build for all other modules depending on the older parent pom. I get the error message

```
Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact company:modbase:pom:2.0.6 
in mirrored.repo.com (http:((mirrored.repos.com/pub/java/maven2) and 
'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM ...
```

The desired older parent pom is deployed at a remote maven repository specified in the pom file, however, maven tries to search in a repo specified as mirror in settings.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a separate maven module out of the parent pom and after changing it make a new release which results in a new version which can be used as parent in other modules.

Comment: True, it may solve the problem of common dependencies. Using one parent pom specifying modules and one dependent pom specifying common dependencies. Adding more modules in the parent pom without renumbering all module versions could be made if the parent pom always is deployed as snapshot. Not nice but it solves the problem. Thank you.