# Have a Pom.xml Download and Reference a Parent Pom

Tags: maven

I have a Pom.xml I was wondering if there is a way to have the Pom download the Parent pom from somewhere then reference the parent Pom.

Edit: I'm having issue with the parent pom, this is the parent Pom I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>dev</groupId>
    <artifactId>company-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>Artifactory</id>
        <name>Artifactory-releases</name>
        <url>http://artifactory:8081/artifactory/dev</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>Artifactory</id>
        <name>Artifactory-snapshots</name>
        <url>http://artifactory:8081/artifactory/dev</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>

</project>
```

I have uploaded the parent Pom.xml to artifactory, here is my Pom.xml.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>maven.Test</groupId>
  <artifactId>Hello</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Artifactory</name>
  <url>http://artifactory:8081/artifactory/webapp/home.html?0</url>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.8.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

<parent>
  <groupId>dev</groupId>
  <artifactId>company-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</parent>

</project>
```

But when I run it I get this error

```
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for maven.Test:Hello:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could n
ot find artifact dev:company-parent:pom:1.0.0 in central (https://repo.maven.a
pache.org/maven2) and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 22,
 column 9 -> [Help 2]
```

How do I have my Pom find the artifact in my artifactory instance?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you mean. The parent POM gets automatically downloaded and installed in the local repository.

Comment: Ah okay let me try to explain this better, I want to have the Parent Pom hosted somewhere, like on Artifactory. I then want the Pom.xml, that would be on my computer, to run a command to download the parent Pom and reference it. Does that help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download parent pom from remote repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12566835/download-parent-pom-from-remote-repository)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You parent `pom` should be `pom` with `packaging` type of `pom`. e.g:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
< project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" >
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

</project>
```

The `pom`, mentioned above, you can deploy to artifactory and after that you can reference it as parent pom in the child `pom`. e.g:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>child</artifactId>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Artifactory-Releases</id>
            <url>http://artifactory:8081/artifactory/dev</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>Artifactory-Snapshots</id>
            <url>http://artifactory:8081/artifactory/dev</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Comment: @EngineerDollery, thanks. it came from IDE when I've created a test project :)

Comment: Would this work even if the Parent pom was hosted somewhere else? Wouldn't I need to have a link or something to where the parent pom is? I currently have my Pom referencing a parent using a relative path.

Comment: It will work if the pom will be deployed to any maven repository. And this repository will be configured in the pom.

Comment: @Macauley Your POM needs to match the parent POM's coordinates (`groupId`, `artifactId` and `version`). Your parent POM has `dev:company-parent:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` but the child POM is referencing `dev:company-parent:1.0.0`; your child POM is missing the `-SNAPSHOT` part.

Comment: I edited it to match and I'm still getting the same error, to have my Pom get the Parent Pom from my artifactory should I edit the links at the top of my code to point to artifactory?

Comment: @Macauley - I've edited the answer with relevant `repositories` element